# Playing a sound gives errors in Mathematica 10.3

Tags: sound

I tried this

```
Play[Sin[2 Pi 440 t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

and it gives errors.

[image]

What is wrong with my *Mathematica*( v10.3)?

**Update**

I found what cause this warning message

It is because I add

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal" -> True]
```

into my init.m file.

But why? What does this warning message mean?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem with V10.3.1 running on OS X. Did you try your code with a clean kernel? Or with a new _Mathematica_ session?

Comment: In addition to m_goldberg's suggestions you can try [resetting defualts](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464). This often clears up really weird behavior.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem the user is experiencing can not be reproduced by others.

Comment: Can't reproduce this either on my win8.1 v10.3.1 system

Comment: @m_goldberg Sorry for late reply. I found the cause and updated my post.

Comment: It also applies in version 9. I, for one, would be interested in knowing what `Play` is doing that causes this weird message. There is nothing undefined in the input that ought to result in a partial compilation. (N.B.: `ListPlay` also produces it.)

Comment: @OleksandrR. So I can expect this post to be reopened now : )